BigQuery - #standardSQL giving error for Correlated Subqueries
I have two tables like:
table_1          table_2
ID  CODE         ID  CODE
aa  r            qq  r
aa  k            ff  k
aa  s            aa  r
bb  r            aa  k
bb  k            aa  s
cc  r            bb  r
dd  r            bb  k
dd  k            bb  s
ee  s            cc  k
                 cc  s

I need to concatenate them vertically, taking all from table_1 and bringing from table_2 ONLY the rows with ID equal to table_1. But from those rows ONLY take the ones where CODE is not present within the corresponding ID of table_1.
Basically this result:
ID  CODE     
aa  r           
aa  k           
aa  s           
bb  r           
bb  k           
cc  r            
dd  r           
dd  k           
ee  s 
      
bb  s
cc  k
cc  s

The solution
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, CODE
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_1 t1
  WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID 
        AND t2.CODE NOT IN ( SELECT CODE FROM table_1 WHERE ID = t2.ID)
);

provided by @SelVazi gives me the error
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN
It works in mysql.
Help?

This can be done using EXISTS :
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, CODE
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table_1 t1
  WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID 
        AND t2.CODE NOT IN ( SELECT CODE FROM table_1 WHERE ID = t2.ID)
);

Demo on mysql

It gives me the error "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."

Make sure to enable standard SQL first.

Isn't it already by default!? I think it is. In fact, if I select Legacy in the query settings it doesn't like the UNION token, suggesting to try standard SQL, indeed...

You can set the SQL dialect by including the prefix #standardSQL as part of your query https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/introduction-sql

I tried but it gives me that error.

I have modified the question

I found 2 different ways of doing it in BigQuery, without having to use EXISTS and getting the Correlated subqueries error.

If we only have the two columns ID and CODE, or we only need those two in the final result, we can simply use UNION DISTINCT

SELECT ID, CODE
FROM table_1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ID, CODE
FROM table_2


If we have more columns in the tables, and need all of them, another solution is

SELECT *
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE 
t2.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table_1) 
AND
t2.CODE NOT IN (SELECT CODE FROM table_1 WHERE ID = t2.ID)

